# Angular2 routing click on menu item

Tags: html, angular

I'm using `Angular2`.
Right now a user has to click on the menu item text to go to the page:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">login</a></li>
```

[image]

How can I make sure that when the user clicks on the blue he goes to the next page? (I use flexbox).

Thankyou

Comment: What do u mean by click on the blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like CSS problem to me. `a` elements are inline by default. You can make them `block`-level so they take all available space:

```css
li a {
  display: block;
}
```